# Request method not showing up in this.props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm sorry if my code is extremely amateur. I just recently started working with react-redux and javascript. I feel like I am a bit spaced out when looking at tutorials when it comes to visualizing states and what the store does. So I'm trying to code something to visually see it in code. My code is similar to the default preloaded code from Visual Studio when a new project for ASP.NET Web app w/ react-redux is created. I want to just call an API using redux and pass that information to the page.

For what I've got right now, I noticed that my API is not called, as putting a red light on my actionCreator is not reached.

///////////File 1 CreaterAction and Reducer/////////////////

```
const requestEvents = 'REQUEST_EVENTS';
const recieveEvents = 'RECEIVE_EVENTS';
const initialState = { events: [], isLoading: false };

async function getData(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    return response.json();
}

export const actionCreators = {
    requestEvents: () => async (dispatch) => {

        dispatch({ type: requestEvents});

        const url = 'api\stuff';
        const events = await getData(url);

        dispatch({ type: recieveEvents, events });
    }
};

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
    state = state || initialState;

    if (action.type === requestEvents) {
        return {
            ...state,
            events: action.events,
            isLoading: true
        };
    }
    return state;
};
```

//////////////File 2 My Actual component//////////////////

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { actionCreators } from '../store/file1';



class Events extends Component {
    componenetDidMount() {
        this.ensureDataFetched();
    }

    ensureDataFetched() {
        const stuff = this.props.//!!!! Does not show .requestEvents
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Events</h1>
                <p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server and working with URL parameters.</p>
                {renderData(this.props)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function renderData(props) {
    return (
        <p>{props.events}</p>
    );
}

export default connect(
    state => state.events,
    dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
)(Events);
```

///////////////FILE 3 Config Store//////////////////

```
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { routerReducer, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import * as Counter from './Counter';
import * as file1 from './file1';

export default function configureStore (history, initialState) {
  const reducers = {
    events: file1.reducer
  };

  const middleware = [
    thunk,
    routerMiddleware(history)
  ];

  // In development, use the browser's Redux dev tools extension if installed
  const enhancers = [];
  const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
  if (isDevelopment && typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.devToolsExtension) {
    enhancers.push(window.devToolsExtension());
  }

  const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    routing: routerReducer
  });

  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware), ...enhancers)
  );
}
```

It runs just shows

Events
This component demonstrates fetching data from the server and working with URL parameters.

My guess is that it's because I haven't used/called this.props.requestEvents

Comment: You need to bind the functions that access `props`. `ensureDataFetched() {` needs to change to `ensureDataFetched = () => {` You also dont need to use `bindActionCreators` because `dispatch` is exposed on your component itself, you can just do the dispatch from your component

Comment: If I change ensureDataFetched() to ensureDataFetched = () => { it still doesn't pick up requestEvents.

Comment: What is `requestEvents`? I dont see a prop passed thats called that.

Comment: My understanding is that in the actionCreator the requestEvents would be called to call that API. It was passed in with `import {actionCreators} from '../store/file1';`

Comment: Why dont you in your component just `this.props.dispatch(actionCreators.requestEvents(...))`

Comment: I didn't even know that was possible haha. So I wouldn't need the bindActionCreator now?

Comment: Haha no worries :). Don't pass a `mapDispatchToProps`. `dispatch` is passed to the component. Its cleaner and less verbose